# Application of Banach-Steinhaus to prove a sequence is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let H be a Hilbert space and $\{x_n\}\subset H$ a sequence such that $\langle x_n,x\rangle\to 0$ when $n\to \infty$.

I am trying to prove the sequence is bounded using Banach-Steinhaus using the following sequence of operators: $T_n: H\to \Bbb R, x\to \langle x_n,x\rangle$.

It is straightforward that $T_n\in \mathcal L(H,\Bbb R)$ and that $\forall x\in H, |T_n(x)|< \infty$.

To conclude I need to relate $||T_n||$ to $||x_n||$.

By Cauchy-Schwarz we have $||T_n||\le ||x_n||$ but is there equality here? Othewise my choice of $||T_n||$ won't be relevant.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Yes, there is equality. Choose $x = x_n/\|x_n\|$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel stupid right now

Comment: This is the easy half of the Riesz representation theorem: the map $x \mapsto \langle x, \cdot \rangle$ is an isometry from $H$ into $H^*$.  (The hard half is that this isometry is surjective.)

Comment: Right! thank you for this perspective

Comment: Here $(x_n,x)$ is the inner product, right? It is usually written as $\langle x_n,x\rangle$ to avoid confusion with the open interval $(x_n,x)$ (where $x_n<x$).

Comment: Right! Thank you! just edited the question to remove confusion